# How to join tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join, relationship

I have the following 3 tables:

-- users --
id
firstname
lastname

-- products --
id
name
price

-- purchases --
user_id
product_id

How can i show with (select) which products user with id = 1 have purchased?

Comment: The mysql documentation has great examples on how to do a join: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: I'd start by reading a tutorial. Try: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: keep convention with your table names, change "purchases" to "products_users" to keep track of your pivot tables.

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged with [left-join]?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
select u.firstname, u.lastname, p.name 
from users u
inner join purchases pc
   on u.id = pc.user_id
inner join products p
   on pc.product_id = p.id
where u.id = 1
```

This joins all 3 tables together using your link table of `purchases`.

If you are not familiar with `JOIN` syntax, then this is a helpful link:

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks. What if the Name of the product was in another table.

Comment: @user1273409 then you would join on the table to return the product name

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the products that were purchased by user 1 (and not the username) then a join between products and purchases will be enough:

```
Select prod.name, prod.price 
from products prod 
inner join purchases pur on prod.id = pur.product_id 
where pur.user_id = 1
```

Comment: What would you do if the name of the product was in another table and the products table had a id to that table?

Comment: In that case you will have to add another join e.g if table `ProdName` has the product name then the query should look like: 'Select pn.name, prod.price 
from products prod 
inner join purchases pur on prod.id = pur.product_id
inner join ProdName pn on prod.id = pn.product_id 
where pur.user_id = 1'

Comment: Why do you use abbreviations? pur and pn?

Comment: `pur` is the alias for table `Purchases` and `pn` for `ProdName`. You can either use alias or full table name to refer to columns: `Products.Name`. For further details see: [MySQL Join Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select * from products
where id in (select product_id from purchases where user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Sorry. I had originally wanted to do a join, and then went for the nested query. That 'p' represents the table. So you could do p.id instead of having to do products.id

Comment: How would the query looks like if the productname was in another table?

Comment: Which table? What is that table's structure?

Comment: users and purchases tables is the same. But if the column in the products table is named productname_id. And another table called productnames with the following columns:

-productname_id-
-productname-

if the productname is no longer in the product table but in another.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  
from users 
join purchases 
  on users.id = purchases.user_id
join products 
  on products.id = purchases.product_id 
where users.id = 1
```

if you literally want a list of products

```
select distinct(products.name)
from users 
join purchases 
  on users.id = purchases.user_id
join products 
  on products.id = purchases.product_id 
where users.id = 1
order by products.name
```